# Why is my function for checking if a username is in an array returning 'false' when the username is?

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitch

I am currently working on a Twitch chatbot, and I'm trying to
implement a function which will see if a user is a moderator in a chat
or a global moderator. The function should return true if the user is
a moderator in the channel or a global moderator in the code.
Otherwise, return false. The array of global moderators is
`['toximixes', 'lucidzbot']`.

So far, checking if the user is a moderator works fine on what I'm
using (tmi.js), but seeing if the username exists inside of the global
moderators array is for some reason not working.

Here is the current function I am using:

```
function isMod(user) {
  if (user.mod == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    chnls.forEach(function(val,i){
      if (val == user.username) {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

  return false;
}
```

The function takes one argument, and that is the userstate object as
provided by tmi.js when a message is sent, but for simplicity and
debugging purposes I am using these 3 objects:

```
{
username:"demo",
mod: false
}, // should be false
{
username:"demo-2",
mod: true
}, // should be true
{
username:"toximixes",
mod: false
} // should be true
```

The first two objects work perfectly, but for some reason the third
object stays as false. This is an issue because tmi.js does not
consider the broadcaster (me in this situation) as a mod, and so when
I run commands in my chat, my account appears as `mod:false`.

If that happens, the function is *supposed* to check my username
against the array of global moderators, and if it finds a match,
return true. But, for some reason, it's returning false and no errors
appear for me in the console or in the chat.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Using a for i++ loop on the array, and checking the current item
   against the username;
2. Using a for-in loop on the array, and checking the item against the username, both with strict equality (`===`) then tried the other (`==`);
3. Using the array's `forEach` to check each item against the username;
4. Using `forEach` again to see if the item `includes` the username at all

But so far none of what I'm trying is working. Despite me having all
permissions in the chat, the function -- and by extension the entire
bot -- treats me pretty much the same as a regular viewer.

In fact, this isn't just happening for my username, the function does
this for every non-Twitch-mod *even if they are supposed to be a
global-mod*. What's going on? And how can I fix this?

Comment: The answers describe solutions, but not why the code didn't work in the first place. The issue is that when you call `forEach`, you are passing _a function_. When you then do `return true` from that function, you are just returning from the inner function, but not from `isMod`! Your code would have worked with `for (const val of chnls) { /*code*/ }` instead of `chnls.forEach(val => { /*code*/ })`, but of course there are much more direct ways anyway, as shown in the answers here.

Comment: @Quentin In fact I think it is misleading that you closed this question as a duplicate for the short-circuiting question, because that's not what the OP intended to do with the `return true`. They intended to return _from the outer function_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to iterate over the array. Array.prototype.includes() works fine.

Try this :

```
function isMod(user) {
  if (user.mod == true) {
    return true;
  } else if (chnls.includes(user.username)) {
    return true
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: You could also use the "||" operator instead of "else if"

Comment: Right, so the shortest way would be `const isMod = user => user.mod || chnls.includes(user.username)`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
function isMod(user) {
  if (user.mod == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return chnls.some(function(val){
      return val == user.username;
    });
  }
}
```

You may need a pollyfil for [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)